# Java - docx4j-ImportXHTML : issue with NamespacePrefixMapper not found

Tags: java, docx4j

I want to convert html content to docx.

I am using docx4j-ImportXHTML and docx4j.

```
String xhtml= "<div>hello world <bold>bold character</bold></div>";

WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
XHTMLImporterImpl XHTMLImporter = new XHTMLImporterImpl(wordMLPackage);


wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getContent().addAll(
            XHTMLImporter.convert( xhtml, null) );

System.out.println(XmlUtils.marshaltoString(wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getJaxbElement(), true, true));

wordMLPackage.save(new java.io.File("/home/out.docx") );
```

I am getting this exception when I call convert method :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Can't create
>   internal NamespacePrefixMapper
>    - with linked exception: [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.docx4j.jaxb.suninternal.NamespacePrefixMapper]   at
>   org.docx4j.XmlUtils.marshaltoString(XmlUtils.java:840)    at
>   org.docx4j.XmlUtils.marshaltoString(XmlUtils.java:716)    at
>   org.docx4j.model.styles.StyleTree.createVirtualStylesForDocDefaults(StyleTree.java:487)
>     at org.docx4j.model.styles.StyleTree.(StyleTree.java:107)     at
>   org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.MainDocumentPart.getStyleTree(MainDocumentPart.java:202)
>     at
>   org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.MainDocumentPart.getStyleTree(MainDocumentPart.java:172)
>     at
>   org.docx4j.convert.in.xhtml.XHTMLImporterImpl.stylesToCSS(XHTMLImporterImpl.java:464)
>     at
>   org.docx4j.convert.in.xhtml.XHTMLImporterImpl.getRenderer(XHTMLImporterImpl.java:271)
>     at
>   org.docx4j.convert.in.xhtml.XHTMLImporterImpl.convert(XHTMLImporterImpl.java:663)

Comment: What versions?  What do you have on your classpath?

Answer (score 0):

Start by upgrading from 3.0.0 to docx4j 8.1.x:  https://www.docx4java.org/downloads.html

(no need to change your ImportXHTML version).

Also you'll need to make sure your HTML is well formed XML.  So enclose your example in a

or  tag.